# 18.04 "sudo apt autoremove" causes error "WARNING: missing /lib/modules/uname"

Tags: apt, dpkg

After updating kernel to 5.0.0-36-generic, an error occurred during install of updates post the kernel update. Specifically, it appears to have manifested itself during the updating of the `linux-firmware` package.

Running the Software Updater or `sudo apt update` in a terminal says all the packages are up to date.

However, Synaptic Package Manager says that `linux-firmware` has not finished installing. If I try to reinstall it I get an error similar to the one shown below.

I've tried `sudo apt clean` and `sudo apt autoremove`. When I do install packages using Synaptic, the install reports errors but the package does install.

Computer boots OK.

The 18.04 install lives on the second of three primary partitions `/dev/sda2`, Ubuntu 16.04 is on `/dev/sda1`, and `/dev/sda3` is empty.

The error is this:

```
martin@computer:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for martin: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.12) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-uname
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/uname
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-uname-r
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/uname-r
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname-r
dpkg: warning: version 'uname-r' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
dpkg: warning: version 'uname-r' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
dpkg: warning: version 'uname-r' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
dpkg: warning: version 'uname-r' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname-r
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-uname
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/uname
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
dpkg: warning: version 'uname' has bad syntax: version number does not start with a digit
depmod: ERROR: Bad version passed uname
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img--r
/usr/sbin/mkinitramfs: option requires an argument -- 'r'
W: non-GNU getopt
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img--r with 1.
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
martin@computer:~$
```

There are currently three kernels on the 18.04 install:

```
martin@computer:~$ ls -al /boot/
total 179196
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Nov 15 22:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root     4096 Nov 14 20:48 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   217480 Nov 12 09:54 config-4.15.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   224516 Nov 11 08:44 config-5.0.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   224516 Nov 12 10:46 config-5.0.0-36-generic
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root     4096 Nov 13 20:50 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 39680508 Nov 13 19:29 initrd.img-4.15.0-70-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 41118914 Nov 13 17:33 initrd.img-5.0.0-35-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 41116325 Nov 15 16:23 initrd.img-5.0.0-36-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 10854263 Nov 15 22:48 initrd.img-uname
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 10854268 Nov 15 22:48 initrd.img-uname-r
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4066166 Nov 12 09:54 System.map-4.15.0-70-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4301791 Nov 11 08:44 System.map-5.0.0-35-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4301791 Nov 12 10:46 System.map-5.0.0-36-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8363672 Nov 12 09:58 vmlinuz-4.15.0-70-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8785656 Nov 11 08:48 vmlinuz-5.0.0-35-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8785656 Nov 12 10:47 vmlinuz-5.0.0-36-generic
martin@computer:~$
```

Comment: Does `sudo apt -f install` do anything?

Comment: sudo apt -f install gives the same error.

Comment: I appear to have solved the issue.

Going by this info:

[link]https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524179/apt-get-dist-upgrade-reports-error-depmod-error-bad-version-passed-uname-a[/link]

Removed "uname", "uname-r" and "uname -r" from /var/lib/initramfs-tools/

Removed "initrd.img-uname", "initrd.img-uname-r" and "initrd.img-uname -r" from /boot/